# what address does pointer store on assigning a string?

Tags: c, pointers

```
char *p="Good Morning";
```

What address does pointer `p` store?
Every character of "Good Morning" has a different address so p should be storing "G" address initially.  How does the pointer increment itself to next location?

Answer (score 2):

`p` starts out pointing at the `'G'`.

In C it is understood that `char*` pointers when used to indicate a string are pointing at the first character. The end of such a string is meaked with an implicit `'\0'` char.

The pointer does not increment itself, but the functions that use it as a string ( e.g. `puts(p)` ) will do that internally.

Answer (score 0):

> What address does pointer p store? Every character of "Good Morning"
>   has a different address so p should be storing "G" address initially.
>   How does the pointer increment itself to next location?

The pointer stores the address of the first character of the string. (e.g. `*p` is the same as `p[0]` and is the value stored at that address -- `G`)

The pointer increment is defined by the pointer `type`. A pointer to a string, or more properly `char *` has a type size of `1` (`sizeof (char)`), so incrementing the pointer (e.g. `p++;` or `p += 1;`) will increment the pointer by `1 - byte` to the next char.

Similarly, an integer pointer `int *foo` will have an increment of `4 - bytes` (to the next integer) based on the `sizeof (int);` being `4` (normally).